# Why are my buttons not firing when clicked on? - Java/Android Studio

Tags: java, android, performance

So for my final assignment of the year, I have to make a Bingo App with three screens. I've made good progress so far, but for some reason all of a sudden, the buttons on my second screen aren't working at all.

Even though I don't see anything wrong with their on-click methods at a quick glance... The other screens' buttons work, but it's just this one's buttons that aren't firing. Now matter how much I click on the buttons on the activity in the emulator, they simply don't do anything. I'm not sure how I can fix this...

The code of the screens:

```
// The screen in question
public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String BINGO_HISTORY_FILE = "bingohistory.txt";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

        // Get the contents of the array from the MainActivity and display them
        TextView txtCurrent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCurrent);
        int[] NumbersCalled = MainActivity.NumbersCalled;
        final String outputString = getOutputString(NumbersCalled);
        txtCurrent.setText("Numbers called: " + outputString);


        // Event handler for the Go Back to Main Menu button
        Button returnBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReturn);
        returnBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity.NumbersCalled = NumbersCalled;
                DisplayActivity.this.finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(DisplayActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });

        // Event handler for the Save button
        Button saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReturn);
        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Save the current bingo numbers after the game is finished
                writeToFile(outputString);
            }
        });
    }

    private String getOutputString(int[] NumbersCalled) {
        String temp = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < NumbersCalled.length; i++) {
            temp += NumbersCalled[i] + " ";
        }
        final String outputString = temp;
        return outputString;
    }

    protected void writeToFile(String data) {
        // Write the current numbers to the "bingohistory.txt" text file.
        // Check for exceptions when attempting to write to the file
        FileOutputStream file = null;
        try {
            file = openFileOutput(BINGO_HISTORY_FILE,
                    DisplayActivity.this.MODE_PRIVATE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(DisplayActivity.this,
                    "Couldn't find file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
        try {
            bw.write(data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(DisplayActivity.this,
                    "Couldn't write to file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        try {
            bw.newLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(DisplayActivity.this,
                    "Couldn't write to file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        try {
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(DisplayActivity.this,
                    "Couldn't write to file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        try {
            osw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(DisplayActivity.this,
                    "Couldn't write to file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

// The Main Menu's screen
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Declare class-level variables
    public static int currentNumber;
    public static int[] NumbersCalled = {currentNumber};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get the first number to be displayed. Save the number to be displayed
        // in the NumbersCalled array and display the number in the textview
        TextView txtCurrentNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);
        getAndSaveNewNumber();
        txtCurrentNumber.setText(String.valueOf(currentNumber));

        // Event handler for the Exit button
        Button exitAppBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnExit);
        exitAppBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Finish and exit the app
                MainActivity.this.finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        // Event handler for the Next button
        Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Get the next number to be displayed. Save the number to be displayed
                // in the NumbersCalled array and display the number in the textview
                getAndSaveNewNumber();
                txtCurrentNumber.setText(String.valueOf(currentNumber));
            }
        });

        // Event handler for the Bingo button
        Button bingoBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBingo);
        bingoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayActivity.class).putExtra("NumbersCalled", NumbersCalled));
            }
        });

        // Event handler for the Display button
        Button displayBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);
        displayBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayActivity.class).putExtra("NumbersCalled", NumbersCalled));
            }
        });

        // Event handler for the History button
        Button historyBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHistory);
        historyBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HistoryActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    // Generate a new random number and save it to the NumbersCalled array
    // Then proceed to sort the array in ascending order
    public void getAndSaveNewNumber() {
        currentNumber = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (99 - 0 + 1) + 0);

        //Check if number has been called before, if so, don't add to the array nor display it.
        if (checkNumbersCalled(currentNumber)) {
            currentNumber = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (99 - currentNumber + 1) + 0);
            saveNewNumber();
        } else {
            saveNewNumber();
        }

        // Sort the array in asc order
        Arrays.sort(NumbersCalled);
    }

    // Go through the NumbersChecked array and check if n is already in the array
    public boolean checkNumbersCalled(int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < NumbersCalled.length; i++) {
            if (NumbersCalled[i] == currentNumber) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Add a number to the array
    public void saveNewNumber() {
        // Add number to the array
            // Create a new array with the current number
            // then substitute the NumbersCalled array's value with the new array
            int n = NumbersCalled.length;
            int[] NewArray = new int[n + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                NewArray[i] = NumbersCalled[i];
            }
            NewArray[n] = currentNumber;
            NumbersCalled = NewArray;
    }
}
```

The activity/GUI in question:

[image]

Comment: The code looks fine.  Are you *sure* they aren't firing at all?  Try adding a toast/log line, or using the debugger.  My guess is the problem is something else.  Or the layout IDs are on the wrong elements.

Comment: @RyanM I got it! I accidentally linked both returnBtn and saveBtn to the same button (R.id.btnReturn in this case), and thus created two onclicklisteners for the same button. That's why nothing worked.